# Python dictionary doesn't work with 'pass'

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I'm trying to create login_data dict but it wont let me put 'pass' in it, can somebody please help me? Here is my code:

```
import requests

con = requests.session()
URL = 'http://djordjekrstic.eucenik.rs/login.php'
ID = 'xxxxx'
PASS = 'xxxxx'
LoginData = dict(korime='email', pass='password')

con.post(URL, data=LoginData)
res = con.get('http://djordjekrstic.eucenik.rs/roditelj/roditelj.php')
ResContent = res.content

print(ResContent)
```

and here is an error:

```
File "D:/PythonProjects/OsDjordjeKrstic", line 7
    LoginData = dict(korime='email', pass='password')
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) is a reserved keyword. Use `pswd` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is a reserved keyword in Python. Use a different name for that key like `password` or `pswd` and it will work. If you really need the key to have the name 'pass', you can use the alternate way of creating a dictionary like `d = {'pass': 'password'}`.

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is a reserved keyword in Python.  When you use that word, it thinks you are trying to do something special, but you aren't doing it in the right way.  You could try using a different key, or you could create your dictionary with strings:

```
LoginData = {'korime': 'email', 'pass': 'password'}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned `pass` is a reserved keyword and you thus cannot use it to construct dictionaries using the `dict` function.
However, you can still use this alternative syntax:

```
LoginData = {'korime': 'email', 'pass': 'password'}
```